# HTML in PHP Array Element

Tags: php, arrays, forms, drop-down-menu

I have some HTML 'option' code that I need to get into a form. The code is stored in an array similar to this (there are other elements in the array, but this one is the one that I am having problems with):

```
$formcode = array(

'CODEBLOCK' => '<select name="myOptions">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>'
    )
```

On the generated page, the code is put in the proper spot inside the  with this

```
echo $formcode['CODEBLOCK']
```

But the generated page just shows

```
Volvo Saab Opel Audi
```

and not the drop-down expected.

I've tried escaping the `$formcode['CODEBLOCK']`, `htmlspecialchars`, but to no avail.

How do I get the echo `$formcode['CODEBLOCK']` to display the desired `select` statement?

Thanks....

**Added - per comments**

1) The output is inside a `<form>` element. Other `<inputs>` are on the form OK (and come from arrays).

2) Prefer not to use JavaScript. The `<script>` code with `<options>` is properly 'built' (see array element contents above), and should work

3) Page source is
The page source shows this

```
<div  style="float:left;">
            Volvo
            Saab
            Opel
            Audi
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use Javascript

Comment: Can you provide some output page example?

Comment: Your code should work as written. `echo` works the same no matter where the value comes from.

Comment: What do you see if you use `View Source`?

Comment: Is it inside of a form?